# Service Fabric Service reference has yellow triangle

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I'm using VS2015, when I add a service to my service fabric application, the reference has a yellow triangle. My Error window has no errors in it, and when I hover over the reference nothing popups up. How can I find out what it's problem is?

The solution builds and runs fine otherwise.

Comment: Can you do a Build>Clean Solution? Also you can try manually removing all the bin and obj folders.

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET Core service? If so, that's a known issue.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks

Comment: @VaclavTurecek do you have a URL for this known issue?

Comment: @spottedmahn see accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known bug in VS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190258/service-fabric-yellow-triangle-on-the-services.html) - the underlying project configuration system is incorrectly flagging the references as wrong. Things should work normally if you do a build.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error when referencing a class library from the service project. The target framework on the class library was 4.7, which was higher than the one of the service, 4.5.2.

So I just made sure they were compiling to the same framework versions (used 4.5.2 for both projects).