# Yellow triangle on Service reference in ServiceFabric solution

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, .net-framework-version, sln-file, visual-studio-2017

My `SF` solution currently has one service, but seems like there is a problem in the reference from the `sfproj` to the service.

I saw the following question and answer and made sure all target framework is matching: [Service Fabric Service reference has yellow triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365272/service-fabric-service-reference-has-yellow-triangle)

I'm using **Visual Studio 2017**.

[image: SlnExp]

All of these projects are targeting `.NET Framework 4.5.2`, `sfproj` version **1.6**

I also tried to add new services, and they too have yellow reference.

Comment: What does the build output warnings/errors tell you?

Comment: @PeterBons indeed there was a NuGet error, but solution compiled successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with **NuGet** packages.

My local NuGet server only had `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild` version **1.4**, but apparently, the `sfproj` demanded version **1.6**. By manually editing the `sfproj`, problem was resolved.